# Exact solutions to an equation containing arctan

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is there a way to solve this equation for x?

$$\sqrt{x^2+8}-x-4\arctan\left(\frac{x+3}{x^2+x+6}\right) = 0$$

Numerically, I get $x \approx 1.39$, but is there a way I can get an exact solution?

Comment: I've converted your equation to LaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

The solutions can't be algebraic numbers, because if $x$ was algebraic the same would be true of $y = (\sqrt{x^2+8} - x)/4 $ and $z = (x+3)/(x^2 + x + 6)$.  Now your equation says $\tan y = z$, and thus $\cos^2 y = \frac{1}{z^2+1}$, so $\cos y$ would be algebraic.  But by Lindemann's theorem $\cos y$ is transcendental for any nonzero algebraic $y$.

Comment: +1 I did not think the theory about the existence of algebraic solutions is so strong.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Wims Function Calculator](http://wims.unice.fr/wims/wims.cgi?session=5998E1CB56.6&%20lang=en&%20cmd=resume&%20module=tool/analysis/function.en), the solution is
$$
x \approx 1.39370747885618057089248282982,
$$
and is not recognized by the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=1.39370747885618057089248282982&lookup_type=simple).

EDIT: Wims Function Calculator further gives
$$
x \approx 1.3937074788561805708924828298190336450650412142437367971287022786222374715488762515547338431838298094439414865124475411133191132591019104894926923243497788034792713333649381694869738035510413209296893.
$$
However, the result from the Inverse Symbolic Calculator indicates that a "closed-form" solution is not likely to exist.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question of the OP.

Comment: It answers the question in the negative.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: It's very unlikely that a closed-form solution to this type of equation exists.  On the other hand, the Inverse Symbolic Calculator doesn't really rule out moderately complicated "closed-form" numbers.  For example, there is no match to
$\arctan(\sin(2)+\cos(3)+\tan(4))$.

Comment: @Robert, indeed, good point. Still, it is helpful for the OP to know that, in the present case, ISC rules out simple solutions (loosely speaking, of course).